# Firebase Cloud Messaging error for services component

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Firebase Cloud Messading and i have an issue in my Manifest file, it complains with a message "Cannot resolve MyFirebaseMessagingService under service" below is my Manifest file snippet. Could anyone have any idea of what went wrong?, this is AndroidStudio 2.2

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: show your gradle file

Comment: Did you define a class `MyFirebaseMessagingService` in your code? Is the class `public`? Is it in the package that you defined in your manifest file?

Comment: this could help [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37674805/4154016)

Comment: update your firebase dependency and rebuild code

Comment: I actually figured out that the class was private and i changed them to public and it worked, thanks for the response

Comment: Sir @FrankvanPuffelen, how to properly use the messagingService ? , do i need to set every class which has onMessageReceived as service ? or people use it only in mainActivity ?